# newcommand: different behavior depending on number of args?

Tags: macros

I want to make my citations simpler. I'm in theoretical physics where citations are numbered, so `\cite{citation}` will pull up simply "[1]" (for example). Common usage is to write "Ref. [1]." I made a new command which handles this:

```
\newcommand{\rcite}[1]{Ref.~\cite{#1}}
```

What I'd like to do is extend this to know if I've passed it 2 or more arguments and, in that case, change Ref. to Refs. But I have not even the slightest idea how to do this, and my look through the documentation came up empty. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I do not assume, that you want to make more than 9 references in a row, otherwise you would encounter problems, since there are no more than 9 parameters allowed for macros. I would suggested a csv-list instead.

Comment: @egreg I do use cleveref, but I don't think it handles citations?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, although when I tried to define two different commands with the same name but different numbers of arguments, it threw an error.

Comment: @Adam: Of course ... I will see, if a non-cleverref solution is possible. cleverref works with lists of `\ref`, but I am unsure about `\cite`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a simple interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\rcite}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { , }
   { Refs.\nobreakspace\cite{#1} } % a comma in the argument
   { Ref.\nobreakspace\cite{#1} }  % no comma
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\rcite{a}

\rcite{a,b}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{a} A citation

\bibitem{b} Another

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't cover the optional argument (which is meaningful only for single citations), but it can easily be added.

[image]

The “classical” way to do it can be

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rcite}[1]{%
  \rcite@aux#1,\@nil{#1}%
}
\def\rcite@aux#1,#2\@nil#3{%
  \if\relax#2\relax
    % just one key
    Ref.~\cite{#3}%
  \else
    Refs.~\cite{#3}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

---

A more complex interface, where it's allowed to get

> Refs. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAgND.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbIaI.png)

with the `\rcite*` form. Also the optional argument is allowed, but it assumes just one cited item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\rcite}{som}
 {
  \IfValueTF{#2}
   { Ref.\nobreakspace\cite[#2]{#3} }
   {
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
     { \adam_rcite_sep:n { #3 } }
     { \adam_rcite_simple:n { #3 } }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__adam_rcite_items_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \adam_rcite_simple:n #1
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { , } { Refs } { Ref }
  .\nobreakspace
  \cite{#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \adam_rcite_sep:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__adam_rcite_items_seq
  \int_compare:nTF { \clist_count:n { #1 } > 1 }
   { Refs }
   { Ref }
  .\nobreakspace
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__adam_rcite_items_seq { \cite{##1} }
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__adam_rcite_items_seq { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Optional argument: \rcite[p.~3]{a}

One: \rcite{a}; two: \rcite{a,b}; three: \rcite{a,b,c}

One: \rcite*{a}; two: \rcite*{a,b}; three: \rcite*{a,b,c}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{a} A citation

\bibitem{b} Another

\bibitem{c} Again

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does precisely what I need. Thanks! Is there a solution without using new packages?

Comment: @Adam I was just going to add it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution for (infinite) number of references, just using a comma-separated list with `etoolbox` package.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}%

\listgadd{\myreferencelist}{}%

\newcounter{listcounter}


\newcommand{\rcite}[1]{%
\undef\myreferencelist%
\setcounter{listcounter}{0}
\forcsvlist{\listgadd{\myreferencelist}}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
\stepcounter{listcounter}%
}%
\dolistloop{\myreferencelist}%
\ifnumgreater{\number\value{listcounter}}{1}{%
  Refs. 
}{%
  Ref.
}%
\edef\mytemp{\number\value{listcounter}}%
\setcounter{listcounter}{0}%
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{listcounter}%
  \cite{##1}%
  \ifnumequal{\mytemp}{1}{%
  }{%
    \ifnumequal{\number\value{listcounter}}{\mytemp}{
      }{%
        ,
      }%
    }%  
  }%
  \dolistloop{\myreferencelist}%
}%



\bibliography{biblio}

\begin{document}

% CSV - List
\rcite{Lam94, GSM97,Lam94}

% Just one reference
\rcite{Lam94}

\printbibliography%


\end{document}
```

[image]